# What is -D in vm arguments what it indicates why we have to specify always -D in vm arguments

Tags: java

What is -D in vm arguments what it indicates why we have to specify always -D in vm arguments. Is there any standard? if yes what is that and where it is specified.

Comment: `java -help` :: *-D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property* See also [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Answer (score 1):

The -D sets property values the java program currently running has access to. It allows the programmer to set values that are needed for the program to run but the program doesn't know what those values are so the user has to set them. This can be as simple as setting a file path or a resource location to more complex things that change the behavior of the program.

Take the example below

```
String value = System.getProperty("foo");
System.out.println("My value is: " + value);
```

Then when you run the program such as:

```
java -Dfoo="bar" -jar MyProg.jar
```

you will see the output as:

```
My value is: bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The -D option is for passing system properties to the JVM.  The name / value pairs are added to the `System` properties object, and may be used during JVM initialization.

> why we have to specify always -D in vm arguments

<sup>(If you are asking why all command line options in the `java` command that could be construed as *"VM arguments"* start with `-D` ... you are mistaken.  Many of them don't start with `-D`.  Check the [`java` command manual page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#CBBIJCHG).)</sup>

If you set the properties in (your) code using `System.setProperty(...)`, the JVM may have already looked up the property before your code runs.  A lot of the JVM's initialization is triggered by class loading / static initialization.  It is often difficult to get your code to run before the relevant static initialization.

On the other hand, a typical application doesn't need to have system properties set.  The default settings are typically good enough.

> Is there any standard? if yes what is that and where it is specified.

There are a number of system properties that the JVM recognizes.  They are documented in the javadocs and other places, but there is no single page that covers them all (AFAIK).

But your code and 3rd-party libraries can also define their own system properties.

References:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

The above list is not exhaustive ...