# Java VM argument type -D and --

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, jvm

This might be a trivial question I am asking, but I did not get this required info in any docs, may be I am overlooking. Currently I am using OpenJDK 8.

**EDIT:**

Apologies, specific use case, I am running Spring boot jar.

While passing JVM arguments we options like

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

But lately I have found that instead of `-D` many places I found `--`

```
--spring.profiles.active=local
```

It would be great to know about both and difference and where to use them.

Comment: See [`java -help`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html)

Comment: There's no special meaning of `--test-key=testvalue`, is there? It depends on how your main method processes the args.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do JVM arguments start with "-D"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745261/why-do-jvm-arguments-start-with-d)

Comment: And/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366184/what-is-d-in-vm-arguments-what-it-indicates-why-we-have-to-specify-always-d-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html) command is:

> `java [options] mainclass [args ...]`

There are alternatives where you specify something other than `mainclass`, but the important part is that `options` comes before that part and `args` comes after that part, i.e. they cannot be intermingled.

The `java` command supports many options, one of which is:

> `-Dproperty=value`
>
> Sets a system property value. The *property* variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The *value* variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If *value* is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`).

So that it handled by the Java runtime.

`args` is a list of program arguments, and is handled by Java code, which means they can be anything. It's up to the code processing them to decide where they mean.

A Spring program uses a [`SpringApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html) method to process those arguments. See your `main` method:

> Register a [`CommandLinePropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/CommandLinePropertySource.html?is-external=true) to expose command line arguments as Spring properties.

See the javadoc for more detail.

Spring also has a `PropertySource` for making Java System Properties available as Spring Environment properties, which is why Spring can use properties defined either of these commands:

```
java -Dfoo=bar mainclass

java mainclass --foo=bar
```